# Handle EJB Transaction Timeouts for a loop

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

I have a method to process large amount of files. Thing is this method will timeout when file sizes are increasing. I’m using container managed transactions for the method.

What I did was I spilted the files into lists and offer to do the operation in another method which decorated as @REQUIRES_NEW.

I’m looping through the list on a new method with a new transaction. But when something happens in a middle of the iteration only that transactions will rollback. It won’t rollback previous iterations. I want to rollback the previous iterations as well.

I can’t consider the whole operation as a one because of the timeout issue. Looking for a feedback on this.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the following approach:
When client requests for a files processing (startProcessing), server (EJB) starts background thread (e.g. quartz-scheduler.org) for handling files and returns id of the operation in progress. If neccessary then client can cancelProcessing, getProcessingStatus etc. using such id.

Answer (score 0):

Check about increasing transaction timeout for your ejb method, for eg, if you are using stateless bean , you can simply annotate

```
 @StatelessDeployment(transactionTimeout=10)
```

Another option is , check about **EJB  Asynchronous methods**

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html

Asynchronous methods are typically used for long-running operations, for processor-intensive tasks, for background tasks, to increase application throughput, or to improve application response time . Once the process is over, you can get the status of the process.